# How do you add the dynamic date filter to the query filter in PowerAutomate?

Tags: arrays, powerapps, power-automate, powerapps-formula

I am trying to add a filter to look back 30 days and 180 forward, this giving a really hard time, and I tried everything possible to make this work, but I am stumped and could not figure it out. Can anybody please tell me, how to make this work? I am trying every single option online for a week now. This date filter killing me.

What I am trying to Filter (createdDateTime)

[image]

What I tried so far

```
FormatDateTime('createdDateTime', 'yyyy-mm-dd') ge formatDateTime(addDays(utcNow(),-30),'yyyy-MM-dd') 
AND formatDateTime(addDays(utcNow(), 180),'yyyy-MM-dd')


FormatDateTime(triggerBody()?['createdDateTime'],'yyyy-MM-dd') ge formatDateTime(addDays(utcNow(),-30),'yyyy-MM-dd')
```

Getting another error for above "One or more fields provided is of type 'Null', a different type is expected."

[image]

[image]

Thank you so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

From Date:

```
formatDateTime(triggerBody()?['From'],'yyyy-MM-dd')
```

To Date:

```
formatDateTime(triggerBody()?['To'],'yyyy-MM-dd')
```

[image: formatDateTime(triggerBody()?['From'],'yyyy-MM-dd')]